# Indexing with pandas df..loc with duplicated columns - sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to add a row to a pandas dataframe with using `df.loc[rowname] = s` (where s is a series).
However, I constantly get the `Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` ValueError.

I presume that this is due to having duplicate column names in `df` as well as duplicate index names in `s` (the index of `s` is identical to `df.columns`.

However, when I try to reproduce this error on a small example, I don't get this error. What could the reason for this behavior be?

```
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'a'], data=[[1, 2, 7], [5, 4, 5], ['', '', '']])
b=pd.DataFrame(columns=a.columns)
b.loc['mean'] = a.replace('',np.nan).mean(skipna=True)
print(b)

        a    b    a
mean  3.0  3.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think duplicated columns names should be avoid, because then should be weird errors.

---

It seems there are non matched values between index of Series and columns of DataFrame:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'a'], data=[[1, 2, 7], [5, 4, 5], ['', '', '']])

a.loc['mean'] = pd.Series([2,5,4], index=list('abb'))
print(a)
```

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

One possible solution for deduplicated columns names with `rename` columns:

```
s = a.columns.to_series()
a.columns = s.add(s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0',''))
print(a)
   a  b a1
0  1  2  7
1  5  4  5
2
```

Or drop duplicated columns:

```
a = a.loc[:, ~a.columns.duplicated()]
print(a)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  5  4
2
```